# Display template is not picked from Object template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-templates

I am trying to create DisplayTemplates -> Object.cshtml template and from it pickup property templates for specified fields. I will provide example to show the problem.

The view model

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }        
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]        
        public string DateStamp { get; set; }  
}
```

I want to display this model in `View.cshtml` like this

```
@model CAWP.Models.UserViewModel

     <fieldset>
         <legend>User Information </legend>
         @Html.DisplayForModel(Model)
    </fieldset>
```

My ASP.NET MVC DisplayTemplates folder has two files `Object.cshtml` and `Date.cshtml`.

The `Object.cshtml` looks like

```
  @foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(p => p.ShowForDisplay))
  {
      <div class="display-label">@prop.DisplayName</div>
      <div class="display-field">@Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)</div>      
  }
```

The `Date.cshtml` is created special for `UserViewModel.DateStamp` property

```
<time datetime="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue" data-date-format="date"></time>
```

So the problem is that `@Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)` in `Object.cshtml` never put `UserViewModel.DateStamp` into `Date.cshtml` template. Any ideas why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was

```
@Html.DisplayForModel(Model)
```

should be

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

I have no idea how these two are differt.